# Permutation and Combination of 4 letters from a $11$ letter word

Tags: permutations, combinations

> Find the number of [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) and [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of $4$ letters taken from the word EXAMINATION.

-from [Arihant Algebra](https://www.amazon.in/Skill-Mathematics-Algebra-Main-Advanced/dp/9313191881/ref=asc_df_9313191881/?tag=googleshopdes-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=397083267002&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=12655484614284434090&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9299484&hvtargid=pla-729869744359&psc=1&ext_vrnc=hi)

My work

There are $11$ letters in the word. E,X,A,M,I,N,A,T,I,O,N

Case $1$. When all the letters are different,

But there are $2$ A's, $2$ I'S, and $2$ N'S. (Consider them as 3 different letters).

Now other $5$ letters are repeating once only. Therefore there are $8$ distinct letters.

Then, the number of combinations=$C(8,4)$=$\frac{8!}{4!4!}$=$70$

And number of permutations=$P(8,4)$=$\frac{8!}{4!}$=$1680$

Case $2$. Two letters are alike of one kind and other two letters of another kind'

Like AAII (just for example)

Number of combinations=$C(3,2)$=$3$

Number of permutation=$\frac{4!}{2!2!}$=$6$

Case $3$: Two letters are alike and the other two different

Like AXAO (just for example)

Number of combinations=$C(3,1) \times C(7,2)$=$63$

Number of permutations=$\frac{4!}{2!}$=$12$

Adding the results of Cases $1,2,3$

Number of combinations=$70+3+63$=$136$

Number of permutations=$1680+6+12$=$1698$

Now, according to the answer given in the book, the number of combinations is correct but the number of permutations is wrong, it is $2454$.

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: It'd be much easier to advise/ answer if you gave what exactly is your reasoning behind each step.

Comment: In case -3 , you did $C(3,1) \times C(7,2)$ .. this may lead to case where other two are same. Like the two you choose out of seven can be two N

Comment: @Buraian In case 3, the two same letters can either be $2$ A's, $2$ I's, or $2$ N's. and for each case, 7 different letters. For example, for $2$ A's $7$ different's are I,N,E,X,M,T,O.

Comment: Could you explain how exactly you wrote down the permutation equations? Why did the pool of items to choose from reduce to four in the second and third case?

Comment: @Buraian In case $1$, all the letters are different. We have to choose $4$ different letters from $8$ different letters. Therefore permutation=$P(8,4)$. In case $2$, There are $4$ letters in the word to be formed but $2$ are alike of $1$ kind and $2$ are alike of another kind. therefore permutation=$\frac{4!}{2!2!}$. In case $3$, Out of 4 letters 2 are alike of one kind. Therefore permutation=$\frac{4!}{2!}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that in case $1$, you are finding permutation correctly but in other cases you are not. What you are finding in other cases is just the ways to arrange letters once you have chosen them. To find permutation, you should multiply combinations with the ways to arrange chosen letters.

Take case $1$.

Number of ways to choose $4$ letters = $8 \choose 4$

Number of ways to arrange = $4!$ (as all letters are different).

So permutation for case $1 = 4! \times {8 \choose 4} = 1680$ (this one is correct).

Where are you doing that for case $2$ and case $3$? Does that explain?